# Web browser where the tabs list is vertical

Tags: web-browser

Once upon a time the tabs list of Opera browser could be configured to the left side of the window, instead of on top.

Apparently this has been removed. **Am I right?**

**Is there any web browser still allowing a vertical list of tabs?**

> What OS should it run on? What other features are important for you (e.g. personalization, addon support)? Speaking of addons: have you checked if it can be achieved via one of those? Like e.g. Vertical Tabs Reloaded does for Firefox? – Izzy♦

To be run in macOS. I'm open to Chromium plugins, but not to Firefox plugins.

---

**Post accept note**: if you know a way using Safari, I'm reading.

Comment: What OS should it run on? What other features are important for you (e.g. personalization, addon support)? Speaking of addons: have you checked if it can be achieved via one of those? Like e.g. [Vertical Tabs Reloaded](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vertical-tabs-reloaded/) does for Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll skip the Opera part of the question since I don't use it these days, and since you're not open to FireFox plugins, I can suggest Tabs Outliner (http://tabsoutliner.com) from the Chrome web store. I'd assume it'll run well with macOS & your Chromium-compatible browser of choice too.

It would not give you a native UI of vertical tabs, nor might it directly satisfy your personal preference of vertical tabs (its implementation gives you a vertical **view** of tabs, among other features), but as a vertical tabs fan myself I've been using it happily for years now.

A few vertical tabs related features listed in their plugin description:

> ☀ Complete Overview of all your open and saved tabs and windows, along with custom added notes and marks.
>
> ☀ Flexible and fully editable by Drag and Drop Tree - everything can be easily organized in logical hierarchies and delimited groups; unlike in other similar tools every node can be a parent for any other node, all items can be freely reordered to specify priority or importance. And all of this can be done not only with somewhere saved links - but with open tabs and windows!
>
> ☀ Tree Style Tab feature - those who remember famous Firefox plugin with the same name immediately recognize inspired by it very useful way to relate tabs to one another. This feature relates newly opened tabs to the tab from which they were opened, which automatically builds strong context for all items and nicely visualize tabs relations.

Comment: Even it's not what I exactly asked for, it actually fits my use case. Gets upvote & accept.

Comment: Curious [trivia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333406/202324).

Comment: That's indeed curious. I'll be following it in case anyone has the answer.

Comment: A [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1483539/) you might want to answer.

Comment: I'll just put my suggestion here as I don't have enough reputation to comment over there, and since this is also not an answer. You may want to try ask the developer at support@tabsoutliner.com to see if he could advise.

Personally I've not noticed/been bothered by that behaviour, so I'm unable to assist you here- sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

## Vivaldi

Vivaldi is a chrome-based browser, which is very customizable. It allows you to display the tabs on the left or on the right. Note that the default position for the tab bar is still the common top.

Here's a screenshot of the tab settings (from vivaldi.com):

[image: Tab Settings in Vivaldi.]

You can also have a tree-style tab overview in the sidebar (vivaldi.com):

[image: tree-style tab overview]

#### Links

- [Tab management in Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/features/tab-management/)
- https://vivaldi.com/